# Transforming YAML in Jinja2 prior to rendering in a template

Tags: templates, macros, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have a canonical list of items in a YAML document that needs to be used in various places to render data in different ways using a number of Jinja2 templates backed by macros. My input YAML looks as follows:

```
depots:
  - name: "Manchester"
    cost_code: "H"
  - name: "Liverpool"
  - name: "Bristol"
  - name: "Hull"
  - name: "Glasgow"
    cost_code: "M"
  - name: "Edinburgh"
```

I'm trying to find a way of transforming this so that output is an embellished YAML which is suitable for some of the Jinja2 macros. I need a list similar to the following which is based only on the `name` attribute from :

```
- name: "Depot"
  attrs:
    - name: "name"
      value: "Manchester"
- name: "Depot"
  attrs:
    - name: "name"
      value: "Liverpool"
...
```

Note that this is *not the text output from a template but the transformed YAML that I want to pass into a template.* It would be difficult to use a template and simply output this as text as the output YAML needs to be incorporated in a larger YAML document and will be converted by the template macro en-masse.

It seems that list comprehension and other neat facilities available in Python are deliberately not available in Jinja2, so I'm wondering, is there another way of performing this kind of preliminary transformation? Plug-ins would probably do the trick though I'm resisting the temptation until I'm fully convinced that there isn't a better/simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure will really it help your or not, but you can transform your source yaml inplace (in jinja2 template) and then use the result of transformation in your macro with the combination of `macro`/`call` statements. See the sample:

```
{% macro ConvertYaml(rootName, yaml) %}
    {% set result = [] %}
    {% for dict in yaml %}
       {% set attrs=[] %}
       {% for k in dict | list %}
           {% set v = dict[k] %}
           {% do attrs.append({'name': k, 'value': v}) %}
       {% endfor %}
       {% do result.append({'name': rootName, 'attrs': attrs}) %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ caller(result) }}
{% endmacro %}

{% call(result) ConvertYaml("Depot", depots) %}
   {{ result | pprint }}
{% endcall %}
```

`depots` var here is the source yaml dictionary. `ConvertYaml` macro converts this dictionary into deserved form (as you shown on the second sample) and then passes it to the caller. Caller accepts the result as a prepared (transformed) dictionary, not as the text. So you can do any further transformation with it, pass to other macros etc.

NB: `do` extension should be enable for Jinja2 environment in order to process this code.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the `template` lookup plugin should be of use. You can set the output to a var or `set_fact` host fact, then pass that var into another template.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/template.html